# I have mistake in database

Tags: mysql, sql, null, varchar

When creating a table as follows

```
create table Ticket (
ticket_id integer not null primary key,
AirlineName varchar not null,
CustomerName varchar,
fromCity varchar,
toCity varchar,
fltNo integer,
TicketDate date,
Dtime TIME,
Atime time,
price integer);
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'not null, CustomerName varchar, fromCity varchar, toCity
>   varchar, fltNo inte' at line 3

What might cause this and how to I solve it?

Comment: Uhm... what "mistake" do you have?

Comment: Where to start...  what's the mistake?  What's the problem?  What did you try?

Comment: what kind of DB ? what error ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null,
CustomerName varchar,
fromCity varchar,
toCity varchar,
fltNo inte' at line 3

Comment: sorry for late < but this is the error

Comment: Take a look at the MySQL examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-tables.html  Your `varchar` columns need to have a length specification, such as `varchar(50)` for 50 characters.  As a hint going forward, whenever MySQL indicates where you have a syntax problem, the issues is _just_ before where it tells you.  The reason is because it failed to parse when it got to a certain point because you made a mistake immediately before that point.

Comment: Good edit. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @JamesWebster Yeah, but it seems [the dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675565/i-cant-solve-error-in-database) now has answers making my work redundant. The OP should really not post dupes.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Ticket (
ticket_id INT NOT NULL primary key,
AirlineName varchar(255) not null,
CustomerName varchar(255),
fromCity varchar(255),
toCity varchar(255),
fltNo INT,
TicketDate date,
Dtime TIME,
Atime time,
price int);
```