# I cant solve error in database

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have mistake in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675148/i-have-mistake-in-database)

```
create table Ticket (
ticket_id integer not null primary key,
AirlineName varchar not null,
CustomerName varchar,
fromCity varchar,
toCity varchar,
fltNo integer,
TicketDate date,
Dtime TIME,
Atime time,
price integer);
```

Please help me, I can't find the error.
the program is my sql, and this is the error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null,
CustomerName varchar,
fromCity varchar,
toCity varchar,
fltNo inte' at line 3

Comment: You get an error message? It doesn't work as you expect? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: What database system are you using? Mysql, postgreSQL...?

Comment: Good point @VitorBraga, I can't tell what this is supposed to be just looking at it

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null,
CustomerName varchar,
fromCity varchar,
toCity varchar,
fltNo inte' at line 3

Comment: Please don't post duplicates. Edit your original closed question to contain all the relevant content. Simply posting your question again is not the correct approach.

Comment: Edit your original question. Insert the error message and relevant details there.

Comment: @tara7el, don't just post comments. Edit the question to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I know it's MySQL:

Your varchars should have lengths (and phpMyAdmin appears to use INT instead of integer, but both seem to be valid)

```
CREATE TABLE Ticket(
ticket_id INT PRIMARY KEY ,
AirlineName VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
CustomerName VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
fromCity VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
toCity VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
fltNo INT,
TicketDate DATE,
Dtime TIME,
Atime TIME,
price INT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution... 
In your case, you use mysql, so this is the correct syntax. 
Remember to put the VARCHAR length...

```
 create table Ticket (
        ticket_id int not null,
        AirlineName varchar(255) not null,
        CustomerName varchar(255),
        fromCity varchar(255),
        toCity varchar(255),
        fltNo integer,
        TicketDate date,
        Dtime TIME,
        Atime time,
        price int, 
        primary key (ticket_id)
    );
```

Comment: thank you so much mr.vitor braga